# What to do with unused furnace filters?

Tags: furnace, air-filter

I bought furnace filters in bulk. But my furnace is dead and had to be replaced. The old filters will no longer fit. The filter size is not all that common. I wonder if there are other use of the filter besides trying to sell them or give them away?

Comment: Funny that OP specifically said "*besides trying to sell them or give them away*", yet each answer suggest one of those options.

Comment: Funnier still that the OP doesn't consider those options acceptable. I'm curious why.

Comment: @Tester101 - The question is not opinion based,  while there could be multiple uses that does not define an opinion. You are correct about the suggestions - because the context of the question: the intent was they preferred to use them and not trash them. So providing an answer that had both components - the fact that there really are no alternative uses for them, and that they could alternatively 'use' them by donating them to a place that will resell them or install in houses they build - seemed a fair answer.

Comment: @Ken There's a guy on YouTube, that uses them for [dust collection filters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-bOEiHmYsD8).  There are probably a ton of alternative uses, and listing them all here as separate answers is not useful.

Comment: @Tester101 - post the answer (it is not an opinion - just one use).. Although I will say that is one expensive time consuming replacement for an ordinary dry shop vac with a filter. IMO he over thought that one a bit. I want to reuse a $10 filter let me spend $500 to do it and why because I can.  Cheers :-)

Comment: @Ken I just don't think it's a good fit for the site. I asked a [similar question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/3856/33), but closed it myself as too broad  when it started getting too many answers.  This question just doesn't have a answer, and the point of the site is to ask questions that can be answered.

Answer (score 4):

While there might be other uses for them , typically in your home there is not a real alternative use.

Drop them off at a Habitat for Humanity Restore store.